# .NET Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions UriHelper.GetDisplayUrl returns invalid URI

Tags: c#, .net, http, .net-core

I'm new to the .NET framework and I'm having an issue with the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpRequest` interface. I'm trying to use the [GetDisplayUri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.extensions.urihelper.getdisplayurl?view=aspnetcore-2.0) extension but it's returning an invalid URI. Later I pass the URI to `System.Uri.CreateThis()` and the following exception is getting thrown:

```
System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.
```

The `GetDisplayUri` method is supposed to create a URL based on the fields inside the `HttpRequest`, but I can't figure out which parts of the URL go in which fields, and I can't find any examples of this online. I'm specifically wondering how I should be breaking down a URL into the `Path`, `PathBase`, and `QueryString` variables.

For example, say I wanted to build the URL `"http://example.com/route/endpoint?foo=bar"`. I'm pretty sure my `QueryString` is just `"?foo=bar"` but I don't know how to break down the rest of the URL into the other fields. Also let me know if there are other fields besides the three that I mentioned that are relevant for `GetDisplayUri`.

Let me know if anything is unclear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, after about an hour of trial and error, I've figured out which fields map to which part of the url. The general form is `url = [Scheme]://[Host][PathBase][Path][QueryString]` and they each have specific rules about how to connect them (for example, Path and PathBase must start with `/`).

So in the example from the question (`"http://example.com/route/endpoint?foo=bar"`), your HttpRequest object would need the following fields.

```
var request = class_implementing_HttpRequest() {
    Scheme = "http",
    Host = new HostString("example.com"),
    PathBase = new PathString("/route"),
    Path = new PathString("/endpoint"),
    QueryString = new QueryString("?foo=bar")
}
```

This was a bit obnoxious to figure out since the implementation of `GetDisplayUri` is hidden. Hopefully if someone else runs into this, I've saved you an hour of guessing and checking.

Edit: As David pointed out in the comments on his answer, .NET Core is open source and I could have figured out the answer looking [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/940dcb0aba247da054ee435380d533e04944093c/src/Http/Http.Extensions/src/UriHelper.cs#L198).

Answer (score 3):

I might not be able to help you figure where the exception came from but I can give you an example of how to build / reconstruct URLs from the request and query strings.

I have a screen to display list of records. Since there are many of them, I need to support filtering and pagination. Filters are placed as query string, i.e., `?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2`. The pagination places additional page size and current page number on the url as well, i.e., `size=15&page=1`.

Instead of using `GetDisplayUri()`, I have a `UrlHelperExtensions` that takes the current Url, examine the url query strings and add additional query strings (page size & current page) as needed to the url.

```
namespace DL.SO.Project.Framework.Mvc.Extensions
{
    public static class UrlHelperExtensions
    {
        public static string Current(this IUrlHelper url, object routeValues)
        {
            // Get current route data
            var currentRouteData = url.ActionContext.RouteData.Values;

            // Get current route query string and add them back to the new route
            // so that I can preserve them.
            // For example, if the user applies filters, the url should have
            // query strings '?foo1=bar1&foo2=bar2'. When you construct the
            // pagination links, you don't want to take away those query 
            // strings.

            var currentQuery = url.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Query;
            foreach (var param in currentQuery)
            {
                currentRouteData[param.Key] = param.Value;
            }

            // Convert new route values to a dictionary
            var newRouteData = new RouteValueDictionary(routeValues);

            // Merge new route data
            foreach (var item in newRouteData)
            {
                currentRouteData[item.Key] = item.Value;
            }

            return url.RouteUrl(currentRouteData);
        }
    }
}
```

In order to do pagination, I need to keep track of the current page size, count of total items, current page, total pages, start page and end page. I create a class for that, `Pager.cs`.

```
namespace DL.SO.Project.Framework.Mvc.Paginations
{
    public class Pager
    {   
        public int TotalItems { get; private set; }
        public int CurrentPage { get; private set; }
        public int CurrentPageSize { get; private set; }
        public int TotalPages { get; private set; }
        public int StartPage { get; private set; }
        public int EndPage { get; private set; }

        public Pager(int totalItems, int currentPage = 1, int currentPageSize = 15)
        {
            currentPageSize = currentPageSize < 15
                ? 15
                : currentPageSize;

            // Calculate total, start and end pages
            var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(
                (decimal)totalItems / (decimal)currentPageSize
            );

            currentPage = currentPage < 1
                ? 1
                : currentPage;

            // Only display +- 2
            var startPage = currentPage - 2;
            var endPage = currentPage + 2;
            if (startPage <= 0)
            {
                endPage = endPage - startPage + 1;
                startPage = 1;
            }
            if (endPage > totalPages)
            {
                endPage = totalPages;
                if (endPage > 5)
                {
                    startPage = endPage - 4;
                }
            }

            this.TotalItems = totalItems;
            this.CurrentPage = currentPage;
            this.CurrentPageSize = currentPageSize;
            this.TotalPages = totalPages;
            this.StartPage = startPage;
            this.EndPage = endPage;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally I can use the url extension and the `Pager` class on the partial view to construct the pager.

```
@model DL.SO.Project.Framework.Mvc.Paginations.Pager
@{
    var showingRangeFrom = (Model.CurrentPage - 1) * Model.CurrentPageSize + 1;
    var showingRangeTo = Model.CurrentPage * Model.CurrentPageSize;

    if (showingRangeFrom > Model.TotalItems)
    {
        showingRangeFrom = Model.TotalItems;
    }
    if (showingRangeTo > Model.TotalItems)
    {
        showingRangeTo = Model.TotalItems;
    }
}

@if (Model != null && Model.TotalItems > 0)
{
    <div class="list-pager">
        <div class="list-pager-info">
            <span>Showing <strong>@showingRangeFrom-@showingRangeTo</strong>
                of <strong>@Model.TotalItems</strong> entries
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="list-pagination">
            <ul class="pagination">
                <li class="page-item @(Model.CurrentPage == 1? "disabled" : "")">
                    <!-- use Url extension here -->
                    <a href="@Url.Current(new { page = Model.CurrentPage - 1 })" 
                        class="page-link" tabindex="-1">
                        &lt; Prev
                    </a>                        
                </li>
                @for (int i = Model.StartPage; i <= Model.EndPage; i++)
                {
                    <li class="page-item @(i == Model.CurrentPage? "active" : "")">
                        <!-- use Url extension here -->
                        <a href="@Url.Current(new { page = i })" 
                            class="page-link">@i</a>
                    </li>
                }
                <li class="page-item @(Model.CurrentPage >= Model.EndPage? "disabled" : "")">
                     <!-- use Url extension here -->
                     <a href="@Url.Current(new { page = Model.CurrentPage + 1 })" 
                         class="page-link" tabindex="-1">Next ></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

This way the links on the pagination would reflect to the current url with the query strings with it, as well as the page size and current page.

Comment: This is great info and I appreciate the help. I'm writing unit tests for a method which calls GetDislpayUri() and I don't really have the power to change the implementation, so I can't really use this here.

Comment: Oh I see. Since .NET Core is open source, you can take a peek on their implementation? https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Extensions/UriHelper.cs

Comment: Ah, had no clue the extension methods were open sourced. That would have been great a few hours ago. Thanks anyway!